# number of interesting divisors of $9!$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math, divisibility, factorial

> We call natural number $a$, "interesting" if natural numbers $x,y$
> (not necessary distinct) exist so that $a=x^2y^3$. how many
> interesting divisors the number $9!$ has?

To avoid calculations errors question brings this hint: "sum of the digits of the answer is divisible by $10$."

Here is my work:

for $x=y=1$ we have $a=1$ so it is one of the number we are looking for. also we know that  $9!=2^7\times3^4\times5\times7$, from this, we can conclude that $x$ and $y$ can't be $5$ or $7$ (because their exponent is $1$) so we should working on $2^7\times3^4$ and (also should considering $1$).

I don't know how to continue from here. I tried counting all the answers but my result is $16$ which is wrong. (maybe I missed some cases and answer should be $19$ according to the hint)

**EDIT:**

I got these answers:

$$x=2 , y=1,3$$
$$x=4 , y=1,3$$
$$x=8, y=1,3$$
$$x=3, y=1,2,4$$
$$x=9,y=1,2,4$$
$$x=1, y=1,2,3,4$$

Comment: It's not too difficult to find all possibilities for $y$. And for each of them list the possibilities for $x$.

Comment: @Arthur I agree but it may cause some errors as I made too.

Comment: Ok. So, which possibilities have you found?

Comment: @Arthur let me edit my question and add them.

Comment: Concentrate on the exponents of $2$ and $3$ - the powers of $2$ and $3$ have to be split into parts which are a cube and a square. What are the eligible exponents?

Comment: @MarkBennet cubes are $2^3,2^6,3^3$ and squares $2^2,2^4,2^6,3^2,3^4$

Comment: You're missing, among other things, the possibility of either of them being $6$.

Comment: @Arthur Oh you are right.

Comment: @Arthur also $x$ can be $36$. in fact I missed some other possibilities ( hadn't consider multiples  of $6$ for $x$ or $y$)

Comment: Apart from $1$, the numbers of the mentioned form are exactly the "squareful" numbers meaning that every exponent in the prime factorization is greater than $1$. This should it make easy to find the divisors with this property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is trickier than it appears. There are $28$ interesting divisors. Rather than work everything out in detail, I will give sufficient hints so that you can enjoy the hunt.

$x$ can be selected from $1,2,3,4,6,8,9,12,18,24,36$. For each $x$, there are one or more possible values of $y$, including $1$. I leave it to you to discover each possibility. When you count up all the possibilities, you will find $32$ combinations of $(x,y)$ that are permitted.

Here's the tricky part: three of the divisors $(64,576,1728)$ can be arrived at in more than one way; when you remove duplicates, you are left with the $28$ interesting divisors. If you have trouble finding them after these hints, ask in a comment for the list and I will put it in the answer by an edit.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $p^r$ is an exact prime power divisor of $a^2b^3$ then if the exact prime power divisors of $a$ and $b$ are $p^s$ and $p^t$ respectively, then $$r=2s+3t$$

Also note that if $r=2s+3t$ then $p^r=(p^s)^2(p^t)^3$

So the exponent for every prime has to be of the form $2s+3t$ and any non-negative exponent of this form will do.

That should help your counting.